# Matrix Polynomial. Given $M$ is Hermitian, is $p(M)$ also Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question 1
I assume the polynomial is $$p(\lambda)=c_0+c_1\lambda+ \cdots c_n \lambda^{n}.$$

And, if $M$ is a Hermitian matrix, then is $p(M)$ also Hermitian?

---

I think $p(M)$ is also Hermitian. I try to prove it by using spectral decomposition of $M$ and prove the fact $M^HM=MM^H=I$.

Am I correct?

---

Question 2
If $M$ is positive definite matrix, under what conditions on $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_n$ such that $p(M)$ is also postive definite?

I do not know how to start with this.

Comment: you should have at least tried with some linear polynomial say $p(x)=2+x$ to check if it is Hermitian...

Comment: what are your $c_i$? Real numbers? complex numbers?

Comment: Powers of Hermitians are Hermitian.  Scalar multiples of Hermitians are Hermitian.  Sums of Hermitians are Hermitian.  For positive definiteness, this is equivalent to Hermitian and having all eigenvalues positive.  Write $M = P^{-1}DP$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix consisting of positive eigenvalues and use $M^n = P^{-1}D^nP$  to track how each eigenvalue ends up after passing through the polynomial.  (Note that the $P^{-1}$ and $P$ can be factored to the front and back of the polynomial, giving $P^{-1}p(D)P$ as the thing to study.)

Comment: @Praphulla Thanks for your comments. Those $c_{i}$ are not specified but we are asked to restrict them such that $p(A)$ is positive definite.